# Ember js - saving models with relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My server is returning a json data and I have no problem loading the models (page.js, event.js, choice.js) with Ember Data. But when the form is submitted, the JSON data submitted to the server doesn't contain the related models (event.js, choice.js).

Below are my files and the json data.

**Json data returned by backend api:**

```
{
   "data":    {
      "type": "pages",
      "id": "12345",
      "attributes":       {
         "guest_id": null,
         "name": null,
         "email": null,
         "address": null
      },
      "relationships": {"events": {"data":       [
                  {
            "type": "events",
            "id": "67891"
         },
                  {
            "type": "events",
            "id": "90908"
         }
      ]}}
   },
   "included":    [
            {
         "type": "events",
         "id": "67891",
         "attributes":          {
            "event_id": "67891",
            "name": "Event 1"
         },
         "relationships": {"choices": {"data":          [
                        {
               "type": "choices",
               "id": "67891-11111"
            },
                        {
               "type": "choices",
               "id": "67891-22222"
            }
         ]}}
      },
            {
         "type": "events",
         "id": "90908",
         "attributes":          {
            "event_id": "90908",
            "name": "Event 2"
         },
         "relationships": {"choices": {"data":          [
                        {
               "type": "choices",
               "id": "90908-11111"
            },
                        {
               "type": "choices",
               "id": "90908-22222"
            }
         ]}}
      },
            {
         "type": "choices",
         "id": "67891-11111",
         "attributes":          {
            "choice_id": "67891-11111",
            "name": "Diet choice",
            "value": "0"
         },
         "relationships": null
      },
            {
         "type": "choices",
         "id": "",
         "attributes":          {
            "choice_id": "67891-22222",
            "name": "No. of adult guest",
            "value": "0"
         },
         "relationships": null
      }
            {
         "type": "choices",
         "id": "90908-11111",
         "attributes":          {
            "choice_id": "90908-11111",
            "name": "Diet choice",
            "value": "0"
         },
         "relationships": null
      },
            {
         "type": "choices",
         "id": "90908-22222",
         "attributes":          {
            "choice_id": "90908-22222",
            "name": "No. of adult guest",
            "value": "0"
         },
         "relationships": null
      }
   ]
}
```

**JSON data submitted to the server**

```
    {
        "data": {
            "id":"e47e8358-0f18-4607-b958-2877155bf5be",
            "attributes":{
                "guest_id":null,
                "name":"my name",
                "email":"myemail@gmail.com",
                "address":"myaddress"
            },
            "relationships":{
                "events":{
                    "data":[
                        {
                            "type":"events",
                            "id":"67891"
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"events",
                            "id":"90908"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "type":"pages"
        } 
}
```

**/pages/show.hbs**

```
<p>
    <label>Name: </label>
    {{input type="text" value=model.name id="name"}}
</p>

{{#each model.events as |event|}}
    <h3>
        {{event.name}}
        <!-- Rounded switch -->
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switch_input" id="{{event.id}}">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </h3>

    {{#each event.choices as |choice|}}
        {{#if (is-equal choice.name "Diet choice")}}
            <p>
                <label for="diet_choice">{{choice.name}}:</label>
                <select id="diet_choice" value=choice.value>
                    <option value="anything">Anything and Everything</option>
                    <option value="vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
                    <option value="hala">Hala</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if (is-equal choice.name "No. of adult guest")}}
            <p>
                Adult guest
                <div>
                    <button type="button" name="btnMinusGuest" {{action "minusCounter" choice 0 "Minimum 0 guest"}}>-</button>
                    {{input type="text" value=choice.value}}
                    <button type="button" name="btnPlusGuest" {{action "addCounter" choice 1 "Maximum 1 guest"}}>+</button>
                </div>
            </p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}

<p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    {{input type="text" value=model.email}}
</p>
<p>
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    {{input type="text" value=model.address}}
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" {{action "submit"}} />
    <input type="submit" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" {{action "cancel"}} />
</p>
{{outlet}}
```

**/routes/pages/show.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        event: ''
    },
    model(params) {
        return this.get('store').findRecord('page', params.page_id, { adapterOptions: {query: {'event': params.event}}});
    },
    actions: {
        submit() {
            // Create rec
            page.save().then(function() {
                console.log('submitted');
            }).catch(function(reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            });
        },
        cancel() {
            alert("Are you sure?");
        },
        addCounter(item, max_val, msg) {
            let current_val = parseInt(item.get('value'));
            if (current_val >= max_val) {
                alert(msg)
            } else {
                item.set('value', current_val + 1);
            }
        },
        minusCounter(item, min_val, msg) {
            let current_val = parseInt(item.get('value'));
            if (current_val <= min_val) {
                alert(msg);
            } else {
                item.set('value', current_val - 1)
            }
        },
    }
});
```

**/models/page.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    guest_id: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    address: DS.attr(),
    is_e_invite: DS.attr(),
    data_time_submitted: DS.attr(),
    events: DS.hasMany('event')
});
```

**/models/event.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    event_id: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
    choices: DS.hasMany('choice')
});
```

**/models/choice.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    choice_id: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
    value: DS.attr()
});
```

Comment: thats expected. The *default* way to do something like this is to save each model independently. The other way you have is to override the serializer.

Comment: hmm okay.. if i were to save each model independently, how do i extract the related models in /routes/pages/show.js? i know i can get the main model id by this.get('controller').get('model.id'), but how do i get 'event' and 'choice'??

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it, is to save each model independently, as @Lux has said in a comment, but you can also write a custom serializer which will semi-manually prepare a data to be pushed after saving a parent model.

Assuming you're using `ember-data`, it should probably look something like this (see https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/):

Create a file called `serializers/page.js` and put there:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

    attrs: {
        events: {embedded: 'save'}
    },

    serializeIntoHash: function (data, type, record, options) {
        const object = this.serialize(record, options);
        for (let key in object) {
            data[key] = object[key];
        }
    },

    serializeHasMany: function (record, json, relationship) {
        const key = relationship.key;
        const hasManyRecords = record.hasMany(key);

        if (!hasManyRecords || !this.attrs[key] || this.attrs[key].embedded !== 'save') {
            return this._super(record, json, relationship);
        }

        json[key] = [];

        hasManyRecords.forEach(item => {

            let recordData = item.serialize({includeId: true});

            if (relationship.options.deepEmbedded) {
                relationship.options.deepEmbedded.forEach(deepKey => {

                    if (!item.hasMany(deepKey)) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    const deepRecords = item.hasMany(deepKey);

                    recordData[deepKey] = [];

                    deepRecords.forEach(deepRecord => {
                        recordData[deepKey].push(deepRecord.serialize({includeId: true}));
                    });
                });
            }

            json[key].push(recordData);
        });
    }
});
```

and in your `page` model change `events: DS.hasMany('event')` to `events: DS.hasMany('event', {deepEmbedded: ['choices']})`.

Above serializer tells `ember-data` to put each `event` of a `page` as a serialized map into output map of a `page`. In addition, for each `event`, it also walks through each `deepEmbedded` model of a relationship - `choices` in this case - and also serializes them.

Note: the `deepEmbedded` option is not part of `ember-data` and I created it for my specific needs, so it may not work perfectly in every case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed ans. I will try this. I just started this. So If i would like to save each model separately, how do I extract the events and choices from the template file? I tried searching but couldn’t find a tutorial on it

Comment: In a controller, for example in `submit` action, you can use `page.get('events')`. It will give you an array, so you can iterate over it and get `choices` in similar way.